# How to use iptables on varnish cache server to access only by one network and backend server

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, cache, varnish

Hi i  want to allow only one network say `10.10.0.0` to access my varnish edge cache server at `192.168.1.10:80` port also block other 80 port request but the problem is cache server points to a origin server which listen on 80 port in in `192.168.2.0` network.

How could i enable only these two networks to request and fetch inside and output 80 port connections

See attached image:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. Could you provide more detailed information?

Comment: Thanks for asking ,I have attached an image to show what i need in the question please find the image

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should add to iptables rules on 192.168.1.10 this rules:

```
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.10.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```